# Why does local storage save last after javascript

Tags: javascript, html, upload, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

Im currently trying to save the tab.url into html5 local storage when the programme loads then update a css file into the header based on a rule, which are all easy to do. But for some reason the popup.html loads the previous local storage variable and not the recent one.

I was wondering if anyone can help me on this, the code that im using is this;

```
<script language="javascript">
var rule;
var links;
var search;

function loadcssfile(filename, filetype)
{ 
   if (filetype == "css")
   {   
       var fileref=document.createElement("link");
       fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
       fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
       fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
   }

   if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
   {   
       document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
   }
}

function loaded()
{   
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) 
    {   
        var temp;
        temp = tab.url;
        localStorage['tab'] = temp;
        console.log(temp);
    });

    links = localStorage['tab'];
    rule = localStorage['ok0'];
    search = links.indexOf(rule);

    if(search != -1)
    {   
        loadcssfile("./css/styles.css","css");
        loadcssfile("./button/styles2.css","css");
    }
    else
    { 
        // or load other css file 
    }
}

document.getElementById('datacontent').innerHTML = rule + "<br>" + links + "<br>" + search;


function createXMLHttpRequest()
{ 
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {   
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {   
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
}

function createXMLHttpRequest2()
{  
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {   
        xmlHttp2 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {   
        xmlHttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
}

function handleStateChange1() 
{ 
   if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 ) 
   {   
       var data;
       data = xmlHttp.responseText;
       document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = data;
   }
}

function senddata(id)
{ 
   createXMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange1;
   xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://weblinkchecker.forum-source.tk/crawler.php?link=" + links.replace('&','0123456789abcdef'), true);
   xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlHttp.send("&type=anythinghere&anothervar=datahere");
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Successful !";
}  

function handleStateChange2() 
{ 
   if(xmlHttp2.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp2.status == 200 ) 
   {   
       var data;
       data = xmlHttp2.responseText;
       document.getElementById('container2').innerHTML = data;
   }
}

function sendForLinks()
{ 
   createXMLHttpRequest2();
   xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange2;
   xmlHttp2.open("GET", "http://weblinkchecker.forum-source.tk/links.php?link=" + links.replace('&','0123456789abcdef'), true);
   xmlHttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlHttp2.send("type=anythinghere&anothervar=datahere");
}

window.onload = function()
{ 
   loaded();
}

</script>
```

As you can see its a web link checker, there is a bit css that I didn't upload, also there a lot of php using ajax but none of that is having an affect on the code and I also removed any innerHTML functions. Sorry for having such a large piece of code.

if any one could tell me why html5 local storage is saving last it would be a huge help. I tried echoing out data and it just gives out the old data and not the recent. I feel like I hit a brick wall with this one.

Comment: if Ivo's answer worked for you, please don't forget to accept it.  :)

Comment: yeah it was a huge help, I think I still need to get use to using chrome extensions though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your code is quite hard to read, please work on your coding style, for example:

1. Use more than 1 space for per indent
2. Don't place stuff on the same line with opening and closing curly braces
3. Use spaces around `==`, `!=` etc.

This will make your code a lot more readable :)

But on to your problem:

```
// this looks like a callback....
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) { 
    var temp;
    temp = tab.url;
    localStorage['tab'] = temp;
    console.log(temp);
});

// this will most likely get executed BEFORE the callback gets called
// therefore the values just hasn't been changed yet
links = localStorage['tab'];
rule = localStorage['ok0'];
search = links.indexOf(rule);
```

You most likely need to move the rest of the `loaded` function into the callback.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the page so it looks a lot neater now. Also the solution works fine, got it working by placing the loaded() function into the callback and by placing the callback into the window.onload function. Thanks for the assistance.